# Windows 10 don't appear on KDE neon bootloader

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, kde-neon

I installed KDE neon today, i had an error telling me that the installation couldn't be finished, so i left KDE neon by click on shutdown option and just power on my pc to boot on Windows, but my pc boot on KDE neon it worked well, but when I wanted to restart my computer to go on Windows, it wasn't there in the boot options.

So I tried to repair GRUB but it did anything, so I went to uefi settings when I booted so I could change the boot option and boot on Windows.
So here I am asking help because i'm Lost with that.

Should I try to delete KDE neon partition and delete the boot option and try reinstall it ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well like I said before, I tried to delete the kde neon boot option and his partition and redownload the file, reflash my usb drive and reinstall it and it worked, i think it was because of corrupted file so they were bugs but all is fix now !